# How to achieve a 'content smooth fade into viewport' in react js

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, web-frontend

I am trying to get animation [as this website has](https://www.futureswap.com/), content is smoothly fading into the viewport as the user scroll. Can anyone please guide me on how to achieve a similar effect in react js?

Comment: This is you can search to web browsers, this is a site of asking programming problems,first try, if you tried something, and not able to do then you can drop code and ask `specific` problem.

Comment: I had been trying to get this effect in react for 2 days now but failed, that's why asking here

Comment: That's right but drop some code. Anyway. You can use many jQuery plugins.

Comment: I tried that too but can't get to achieve fade animation like that website